# Selection Changed Event using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, listitem

I have a **listbox** that contains a list of persons.
When the user clicks on an item the viewModel should set the currentPerson object to the Object the user has clicked on.

I have to use a ViewModel for this, so **no code inside the MainWindow.xaml.xs**. Any Ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's very simple:

Add a property `CurrentPerson` to your ViewModel and bind it to the `SelectedItem` property of the ListBox.

Something like this:

View Model:

```
public Person CurrentPerson
{
    get { return _currentPerson; }
    set
    {
        if(value == _currentPerson) return;
        _currentPerson = value;

        NotifyOfPropertyChange("CurrentPerson");
    }
}
```

View:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPerson}" ...>
```

Comment: +1: I usually bind to SelectedValue though, i remember having issues with the SelecteItem property.

Comment: @Baboon: That's not a good idea. `SelectedItem` is the whole object. `SelectedValue` is the part of the object defined by `SelectedValuePath`. If you had some problems with `SelectedItem` in the past, that most likely was something else. `SelectedItem` definitly is the correct property.

Comment: One more issue: VS tells me that it can't resolve NotifyOfPropertyChange("CurrentPerson").

Comment: This is just a little helper method that raises the `PropertyChanged` event. You can raise that any way you want

Comment: I changed NotifyOfPropertyChange to OnPropertyChange, is this okay?

Comment: @Goot: If that's the method that raises the `PropertyChanged` event, that's ok, yes.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth yeah i use SelectedValuePath a lot ;)

Comment: @Baboon: Sounds strange, especially in a scenario like this one.